# How to handle phone call while doing live audio streaming in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, handler, http-live-streaming

I am doing an audio online streaming the audio is playing fine both in emulator and device. But the issue is when i make a call to my device simultaneously the streaming also playing. I need to pause and play the audio back while the call is coiming. Can u help how to handle that broadcasting.

```
    public class BhajanStream extends Activity {
protected static final String TAG = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

final String rs_bhajan_uri = "Media URL";
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
AudioManager audioManager;
Button bhajan_play;
Button bhajan_stop;
ImageView loadanim, effectbhajan;
AnimationDrawable loadanimation, effectanimation;
ProgressDialog dialog;
MusicServicePhoneStateListener mPhoneListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bhajan);
    bhajan_play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    bhajan_stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    bhajan_stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    loadanim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loadeffectview);
    effectbhajan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bhajan_effect);

    /*if (mediaPlayer != null) {
           mediaPlayer.stop();
           mediaPlayer= null;    
          }*/


    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // mediaPlayer.reset();

    bhajan_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo Info = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (Info == null) {
                Toast.makeText(BhajanStream.this, "POOR SIGNALS ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
            }



                loadanim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loader_1);
                loadanim.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.loadanim);
                loadanimation = (AnimationDrawable) loadanim
                        .getBackground();
                loadanimation.isVisible();
                effectbhajan.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.effect_bhajan1);
                effectbhajan.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.bhajaneffect);
                effectanimation = (AnimationDrawable) effectbhajan
                        .getBackground();

                     bhajan_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bhajan_start);
                bhajan_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bhajan_stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadanim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                effectbhajan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(rs_bhajan_uri);

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                 mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });
        }

    });

    bhajan_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            bhajan_stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bhajan_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mediaPlayer.stop();
            loadanimation.stop();
            effectanimation.stop();
            loadanim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            effectbhajan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }}

        }
    });

}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    // UI work allowed here

    loadanimation.start();


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {

            mediaPlayer.stop();
            loadanimation.stop();
            effectanimation.stop();
            bhajan_stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bhajan_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadanim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            effectbhajan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } else{
        startActivity(new Intent(BhajanStream.this, SaiStreams.class));
        finish();
    }
    }

private class MusicServicePhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    private boolean mResumeAfterCall = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incoming_number) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Log.i(TAG, "phone active, suspending music service");
            mResumeAfterCall = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Log.i(TAG, "phone inactive, resuming music service");
            if (mResumeAfterCall) {
               mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
public void onCreate(){
    mPhoneListener = new MusicServicePhoneStateListener();
    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
public void onDestroy(){
    mPhoneListener = new MusicServicePhoneStateListener();
    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(mPhoneListener, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much!! for correcting your question. I just wanna add for the users that will read your code: don't forget to add in your manifest the following permission: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
so you have to add this line: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity,you can register a phone state listener by calling `public void listen (PhoneStateListener listener, int events)` in the `TelephonyManager` class. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29). Also,You can call `Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)` to get an instance of the TelephonyManager object.

Comment: @ Huang can u show me an example of how to use this in my code

Comment: @user1051599 I don't have eclipse on hand. Ok, I can show you show code snippets to make you understand how to use it, but I can't test it. Actually, reading the document in SDK is a good habit.

Comment: I will update the code snippet later after I get back home. OK?

Comment: I edited and updated my code and shown how i have used. can u check it.

Comment: I think you should register the listener in `onResume()` method and unregister it in `onPause()` method, according to the lifycycle of Activity in Android. Furthermore, you should unregister the same object. I mean, you don't need to create a new `MusicServicePhoneStateListener` object, just the old `mPhoneListener `.

Comment: I  changed the code. Please notice that I don't have the edit privilege. That means the change will be shown after examined by others. Also, I just changed the codes related to the call state change event.